# Regex to parse formatter string

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a `string.Format`-like method. In order to do this, I am adopting Regex to determine commands and parameters: e.g. `Format(@"\m{0,1,2}", byteArr0, byteArr1, byteArr2)`

For the first Regex, return 2 groups:

- `'\m'`
- `'{0,1,2}'`

Another Regex takes the value of `'{0,1,2}'` and has 3 matches:

- `0`
- `1`
- `2`

These values are the indexes corresponding to the `byteArr` params.

This command structure is likely to grow so I'm really trying to figure this out and learn enough to be able to modify the Regex for future requirements.I would think that a single Regex would do all of the above but there is value in having 2 separate <strike>Regex(es/ices ???)</strike> expressions.

Any way, to get the first group `'\m'` the Regex is:

```
"(\\)(\w{1,1})"  // I want the '{0,1,2}' group also
```

To get the integer matches `'{0,1,2}'` I was trying:

```
"(?<=\{)([^}]*)(?=\})"
```

I am having difficulty in achieving: **(1)** 2 groups on the first expression and **(2)** 3 matches on the integers within the braces delimited by a comma in the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex `(\\)(\w{1,1})` can be greatly simplified.

- You don't want to capture the `\` separately to the `m` so no need to wrap them in their own sets of parenthesis.
- `\w{1,1}` is the same as just `\w`.

So we have `\\\w` to match the first part `\m`.

Now to deal with the second part, really we can ignore everything other than the `0,1,2` in the example since there are no numbers elsewhere so you'd just use: `\d+` and iterate through the matches.

But lets assume the example could actually be `\9{1,2,3}`.

Now `\d+` would match the `9` so to avoid this we could use `[{,](\d+)[,}]`. This says capture a number that has either a `,` or `{` on the left of it and a `,` or `}` on the right.

You're right in saying that we can match the whole string with a single regex, something like this would do it:

```
(\\\w){((\d+),?)+}
```

However the problem with this is when you examine the contents of the capture groups afterwards, the last number caught by the `(\d+)` overwrites all the other values that were caught in there. So you'd be left with group 1: `\m` and group 2: `2` for your example.

With that in mind I recommend using 2 regexs:

For the 1st part: `\\\w`

For the numbers: I'd forget about the `[{,](\d+)[,}]` (and the many other ways you could do it), the cleanest way might just be to grab whatever is inside the `{...}` and then match with a simple `\d+`.

So to do this first use `(\\\w)\{([^/}]+)\}` to grab the `\m` into group 1 and the `1,2,3` into group 2, then just use `\d+` on that.

FYI, your `(?<=\{)([^}]*)(?=\})` works fine, but you can't but anything before the lookbehind i.e. the `\\\w`. In the vast majority of cases where a lookbehind can be used, you can do what you want by just using capture groups and ignoring everything else :

My regex `\{([^/}]+)\}` is pretty much the same as you `(?<=\{)([^}]*)(?=\})` except rather than looking ahead and looking behind for the `{` and `}` I just leave them outside the capture groups that are going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regexes...

```
(^.*?)(?={.*})
\d+
```

Good Luck!